# Was follower node flush request to disk when in zookeeper proposal request stage?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I had seen zookeeper source code , It had very strange operation at cluster .
   We all known when write to zookeeper cluster nodes , the process steps are :

1. Leader send proposal request to all follower and self
2. When follower receive the proposal request , then ack it
3. When leader receive the most the ack response , then send commit requst
4. The follower and the leader commit it

The problem is the step 2 , when follower receive the proposal request , the requst is synced to zk tx log (See the list code) , the commit request only write to memory . But at before ack and after sync to disk time , restart all the node , was the uncommited request is the newest request ?

```
 //  the follower receive the proposal request method , forword to syncProcessor
 public void FollowerZooKeeperServer#logRequest(TxnHeader hdr, Record txn) {
            Request request = new Request(null, hdr.getClientId(), hdr.getCxid(),
                    hdr.getType(), null, null);
            request.hdr = hdr;
            request.txn = txn;
            request.zxid = hdr.getZxid();
            if ((request.zxid & 0xffffffffL) != 0) {
                pendingTxns.add(request);
            }
            syncProcessor.processRequest(request);
        }



 // the SyncRequestProcessor operation , after tx log commit to disk , it response the ack request. Was it ok ?
private void flush(LinkedList<Request> toFlush)
        throws IOException, RequestProcessorException
    {
        if (toFlush.isEmpty())
            return;

        zks.getZKDatabase().commit();
        while (!toFlush.isEmpty()) {
            Request i = toFlush.remove();
            if (nextProcessor != null) {
                nextProcessor.processRequest(i);
            }
        }
        if (nextProcessor != null && nextProcessor instanceof Flushable) {
            ((Flushable)nextProcessor).flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this machine translated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.

After the tx log commit to disk, assume the `txid` of which is N, the write is considered accepted. If restarted all the nodes, the `txid` every node use will be N. After the election succeed, N will be considered committed.

**I think what bother you is that the client actually not received the response of the write, but the write is committed**. This is acceptable as the status of zookeeper cluster remains consistent, just the client encountered a timeout, where timeout means that the request is unknown whether committed or not.